# Can I find the explicit feature map that generates exponent of a kernel?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, k-nearest-neighbour, taylor-series

Let's say I have a kernel $K$, and another kernel of the form :

$$
K' = e^K
$$

now I know how to prove K' is a kernel, I can do it using taylor expansion of $e^x$ around $0$,
but let's say if I want to find an explicit feature map that generates $K'$ given that $\phi(x)$ generates $K$.

How do I do that, or is it even possible? I am thinking something in terms of polynomial expansion of a kernel.